# Why does the Unicode properties for a regular expression apply for this type of string?

Tags: regex, perl, unicode

In the following script, why does the `if` evaluate to `true` and why is the `Has space!` being printed?

The `p{Space}` is a `Unicode` property, right? But the `$_` does not contain a Unicode sentence but an ASCII sentence. How does this script work?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$_ = "yabba dabba doo";

if(/\p{Space}/){
    print "Has space!\n";
}
```

Comment: ASCII is a subset of Unicode.

Comment: @RohitJain:I think that in perl unicode string and ascii strings are not the same.

Comment: Well, I don't know much about Perl, but in any language, all ASCII characters are Unicode. Unicode strings are specially used to match unicode characters. Of course, Unicode strings might not be same as ASCII string. But the vice-versa is of course not true.

Comment: @Jim From a programmers perspective, Perl does not keep strings in a certain encoding. It keeps strings as sequences of codepoints. The codepoint of the space character in your string matches the Unicode “Space” property.

Comment: Also, Unicode matching rules apply when (a) the string contains characters > 0xFF or (b) the regex makes use of Unicode features like `\p`.

Comment: @amon:I thought that `p{x}` is related to a perl string that `Encode` would consider as `utf_8`

Comment: Standard 7-bit ASCII is a proper subset of Unicode, and internally everything in Perl is Unicode.  In addition, the UTF-8 encoding of ASCII leaves all characters unchanged.  The only time encoding or representation becomes an issue is when you are using characters with code points greater than 0x7F.

Comment: There is an *internal* UTF8-flag that declares the *internal* representation of each string. If this flag isn't set, every character is represented internally as a single byte. The reverse isn't true. Perl doesn't have special unicode strings; the string type doubles as binary data buffer and unicode string. The `\p` properties apply also to codepoints < U+0080. You can force unicode semantics for all string operations (strongly recommended!) by `use feature 'unicode_strings` or `use 5.012` (or later), else Perl tries to guess Unicode vs locale semantics.

Answer (score 0):

It's evaluated to `true`, because you have a space (`\s`) inside your string. You could also write something like:

```
if ( $_ =~ /\s/ ) { .. }
```

The point is that it does not check the whole string. When you want to check if the whole string *is* a space, you should write something like:

```
if ( $_ =~ /^\s+$/ ) { .. }
```

Or with Unicode:

```
if ( $_ =~ /^\p{PosixSpace}$/ ) { .. }
```

In your case, you don't use the ASCII range, you use the POSIX-range and as well the synonym of `PosixSpace`. It's also case-insensitive, which makes the original space to your space ;)

The list of synonyms are in *[Properties accessible through \p{} and \P{}](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html#Properties-accessible-through-%5Cp%7B%7D-and-%5CP%7B%7D)* (take a look at point 3239). A list of POSIX character classes and their Unicode and Perl equivalents (the third block is interesting for you) are in *[Character classes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html#CHARACTER-CLASSES)*.

Maybe you wanted to use [\p{PerlSpace}](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#%2a%5Cp%7BPerlSpace%7D%2a).